# Smalltalk ifFalse / ifTrue not working

Tags: smalltalk

Can someone explain why this isn't working how I expect?

```
add: rhsKey
myUnits includesKey: rhsKey
            ifTrue: myUnits put: (myUnits at: rhsKey) + 1 at: rhsKey 
            ifFalse: myUnits add: rhsKey -> 1.
```

Example execution:

> ut := UnitTracker named: 'test'.
>
> ut add: 'seconds'.
>
> ut add: 'seconds'.
>
> ut add: 'seconds'.
>
> ut add: 'minutes'.

It keeps executing through the ifTrue on the first go-round.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ifTrue:ifFalse:` accepts blocks `[ ]` as arguments.
If you don't encapsulate the code you want run on true and false in a block it will be executed before the call to `ifTrue:ifFalse:`.

You also need to surround `myUnits includesKey: rhsKey` in parentheses `( )`, because otherwise the compiler will get confused as to which message you're actually trying to send.

In fact, I'm surprised you didn't get a DoesNotUnderstand exception for that code, as you've effectively sent `includesKey:ifTrue:put:at:ifFalse:add:` to myUnits.

With brackets added as you probably intended, it will look like this:

```
add: rhsKey
  (myUnits includesKey: rhsKey)
        ifTrue: [ myUnits put: (myUnits at: rhsKey) + 1 at: rhsKey ]
        ifFalse: [ myUnits add: rhsKey -> 1. ]
```

So now `ifTrue:ifFalse:` is being sent to the result of `myUnits includesKey: rhsKey`

Answer (score 2):

Put brackets around the statements in the true and false blocks.

Answer (score 2):

Once you grok the keyword syntax, I advise to study/mimic the `at:ifAbsent:` message in Dictionary which could be used like this:

```
myUnits at: rhsKey put: (myUnits at: rhsKey ifAbsent: [0]) + 1
```